# DSolve does nothing on ODE equation system

Tags: differential-equations, nonlinear

I am a beginner with Mathematica and I am trying to get out the solution of the following ODE equation system:

```
eqns = {x''[t] == 2*x'[t]*y'[t]/y[t], 
y''[t] == (-x'[t]^2 + y'[t]^2)/y[t], y[0] == 0, x[0] == 0}
DSolve[eqns, {x[t], y[t]}, {t}]
```

But it returns,

```
(* DSolve[{(x^\[Prime]\[Prime])[t] == 
(2 Derivative[1][x][t] Derivative[1][y][t])/y[t], 
(y^\[Prime]\[Prime])[t] == (-Derivative[1][x][t]^2 + 
Derivative[1][y][t]^2)/y[t], y[0] == 0, x[0] == 0}, 
{x[t], y[t], x[t], y[t]}, {t}] *)
```

So basically, it does nothing. What am I doing wrong? I do not have any initial conditions, so I would like to obtain the solution with the corresponding integration constants.

Comment: Do you have reason to believe that an analytic solution to this set of ODE's exists? If not, then it's possible one doesn't exist, and you will be forced to solve the equations numerically using `NDSolve`.

Comment: In fact, I know that the solutions to those equations (which are geodesics on the half hyperbolic plane), are semicircles, according to my General Relativity book. I also tried to solve them numerically, but I need to specify boundary conditions that I don't have.

Comment: That suggests to me, then, that there is probably some transformation of the functions `x` and `y` in terms of new functions that will allow *Mathematica* to solve the equations. Can't say off the top of my head what that would be, but if you have some idea of what `x` and `y` represent, you should be able to come up with such a transformation (perhaps in terms of angles or something?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [tour] now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although `DSolve` indeed cannot solve the system of ODEs in the question, it can solve the equivalent system,

```
DSolve[{z'[t] == (2 z[t] y'[t])/y[t], y''[t] == (-z[t]^2 + y'[t]^2)/y[t]}, {z[t], y[t]}, t]
    // Simplify
```

where `z[t]` is `D[x[t], t]`.

```
(* {{y[t] -> -((I Sqrt[C[2]] Coth[Sqrt[C[2]] (t - C[3])] 
         Sqrt[Sech[Sqrt[C[2]] (t - C[3])]^2])/C[1]), 
     z[t] -> -((C[2] Csch[Sqrt[C[2]] (t - C[3])]^2)/C[1]), 
    {y[t] -> -((I Sqrt[C[2]] Coth[Sqrt[C[2]] (t - C[3])] 
         Sqrt[Sech[Sqrt[C[2]] (t - C[3])]^2])/C[1]), 
     z[t] -> -((C[2] Csch[Sqrt[C[2]] (t - C[3])]^2)/C[1]), 
    {y[t] -> y[t] -> (I Sqrt[C[2]] Coth[Sqrt[C[2]] (t - C[3])] 
         Sqrt[Sech[Sqrt[C[2]] (t - C[3])]^2])/C[1], 
     z[t] -> -((C[2] Csch[Sqrt[C[2]] (t - C[3])]^2)/C[1]), 
    {y[t] -> (I Sqrt[C[2]] Coth[Sqrt[C[2]] (t - C[3])] 
         Sqrt[Sech[Sqrt[C[2]] (t - C[3])]^2])/C[1], 
     z[t] -> -((C[2] Csch[Sqrt[C[2]] (t - C[3])]^2)/C[1])}} *)
```

An additional integration then gives `x[t]`.  There are four solutions, because the ODEs are nonlinear in both `x` and `y`.

It is surprising how often `DSolve` is unable to solve relatively simple systems of ODEs.

Answer (score 2):

I also get no solution from `DSolve` in version 11.0.1.
But if it any help, here is a solution I borrowed from Maple, which was able to solve it,in Mathematica code, that you could try. (Hopefully future version of Mathematica will also be able to solve this).

The solution contains 4 constants of integrations, since these are two second order ODE's.  There are more solutions given. You would have to now solve for these 4 constants yourself (called them `C[1],C[2],...` etc.. using different initial conditions ofcourse in order to plot these solutions.

```
x[t_] := C[4] - 2*Tanh[t/(2*C[1]) + C[3]/(2*C[1])];
y[t_]:=(2 Sech[t/(2 C[1]) + C[3]/(2 C[1])]^4)/(C[1]^2 Sqrt[(
 2 Sech[t/(2 C[1]) + C[3]/(2 C[1])]^4 Tanh[
t/(2 C[1]) + C[3]/(2 C[1])]^2)/C[1]^4 + (
 2 Sech[t/(2 C[1]) + C[3]/(
 2 C[1])]^2 (Sech[t/(2 C[1]) + C[3]/(2 C[1])]^4/(2 C[1]^3) - (
 Sech[t/(2 C[1]) + C[3]/(2 C[1])]^2 Tanh[
   t/(2 C[1]) + C[3]/(2 C[1])]^2)/C[1]^3))/C[1]])
```

Here is the screen shot showing the other solutions in case you need them

[image: Mathematica graphics]